# How to define cell width for 2 HTML tables with different column counts?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If I have 2 tables:

```
<table id="Table1">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="Table2">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first has 3 columns, the second has 4 columns.

How can I define a style to represent both tables when I want Table1's cell width to be 1/3 the width of the full table, and Table2's cells are 1/4 the width of the table?

**edit:** To clarify after a comment in one of the answers below that suggests to set the table width to 100%, the text in some columns will exceed the natural division width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers so far have got close, but none quite right:

```
#Table1, #Table2 {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

and that's all.

`table-layout: fixed` is to be preferred for all tables where column widths shouldn't depend on cell contents. This is faster and much more reliable than the default `auto` table layout algorithm.

Because none of the columns have an explicit width here (either from a `<col>` element or from the first row of `<td>`​s, they all share the remaining 100% of available width equally between them, however many there are. So you don't have to calculate 25%s or 33%s.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following CSS:

```
.table1 td {width:33%}
.table2 td {width:25%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some CSS:

```
#Table1 td{
    width: 33%;
}
#Table2 td{
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should work

```
table td{
    width:100%;
}

table{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

    <style type="text/css">
        table 
        {
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```